# Best way to program: Switch or Object Orientation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to write a program that has a dynamic div for every li that I click on. 
Heres a fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/aaronyolungz/P8x3z/7/

Every div will have 4 parameters that I want to call independently: name, hometown, major, experience.(all are strings)

As of right now I have one function that contains all 4 variables that change based on the function input but I want to be able to return only the name, or the major, or hometown when I call it. My overall question is, should I keep my code as is and call the variables I want by:

`UserStatement(user).User.name`?

Or should I go for something like this:

```
function user_name(user){return name;}
function user_major(user){return major;}
```

EDIT: Fixed fiddle link

Comment: Why not just use an array, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/P8x3z/8/

Comment: JavaScript is a very flexible language which differs from other languages like Java.

Comment: the only reason is because Im going to switch the id's to the name of the person it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a function that retrieves a model (`UserStatement(userNumber)`), and I don't see a problem for the callers to use something like `UserStatement(userNumber).name`.

As for the switch statement, it could be replaced by a lookup in an array or an object.

And, since the access to the model must be dynamic, you could use an attribute on the elements to tell you what property to access:

```
<ul id="testimonials" data-property='name'>
  ...
```

And access it like this:

```
var userNumber = $(this).attr('id');
var property = $(this).parent().data('property');
added_div = '<div class="testimonial_expanded">' +
  UserStatement(userNumber)[property] + '</div>';
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P8x3z/10/).

Comment: So I can retrieve local variables by calling `function.localVar`?
Sorry if this is obvious and repetitive, I just want to double check and make sure I know how this works.

Comment: No, you'll access the object that you return from the function. It's not a local variable, but the return value.

Comment: So when you say that `UserStatement(userNumber).name` would work, how could this be implemented in the code?

Comment: I updated with more info...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put `name, major, hometown` as attribute value inside a `li`, such as

```
<li data-name="1" data-major="xx" data-hometown="" ></li>
```

Thus you can get these value through `$.data`, rather than putting data in javascript.

reference to jQuery data [api doc](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

`UserStatement(userName).name` is good

Comment: If I was to implement this, would I use $.data-hometown when looking for the hometown?

Comment: I believe it should be $(element).data('hometown'). check the api doc I just added in the answer